# expo problemas con dependencias

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Hoy instalé la última actualización de expo en mi windows 10 y desde entonces no puedo usar ningún comando de expo y npm tambien me falla. Probé de limpiar todo el caché, desinstalar expo, nodejs y reinstalarlo pero sigue igual. Al instalar expo me da muchisimos problemas de dependencias desactualizadas, entre otras cosas que desconozco. También he probado de actualizar todas las dependencias con este comando
 => `npm install -g npm-check-updates` .

Aquí los errores que me salen al instalar expo cli. Mediante este comando 
=> `npm install expo-cli --global`

**Errores =>**

> npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in
>   accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please
>   upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and
>   security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid
>   support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
>
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to
>   upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more
>   fetching  binaries from AWS, smaller package size
>
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained
>   and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please,
>   upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>
> npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in
>   accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please
>   upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and
>   security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid
>   support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
>
> npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in
>   accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please
>   upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and
>   security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid
>   support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
>
> npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in
>   accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please
>   upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and
>   security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid
>   support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
>
> npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now
>   available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this
>   version is no  longer maintained an may contain bugs and security
>   issues.
>
> npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now
>   available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this
>   version is no  longer maintained an may contain bugs and security
>   issues.
>
> C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo-cli ->
>   C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
>   C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo ->
>   C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
>
> envsub@3.1.0 postinstall C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\envsub
>   test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true
>
> "test" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable. "true" no se reconoce como un comando
>   interno o externo,
>
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.12.0 failed (this is
>   probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
>   'C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted
>   {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64): npm
>   WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted
>   {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm): npm
>   WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: envsub@3.1.0
>   (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\envsub):
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: envsub@3.1.0
>   postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push
>   || true`      npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit
>   status 1
>
> - expo-cli@3.11.1 updated 1 package in 70.5s

¿Como puedo solucionar este problema para seguir usando npm y expo?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN=>**

Para solucionar le problema con expo habilite la ejecución de scripts, que al parecer estaba deshabilitada. 
 Este comando para comprobar que la tenia deshabilitada

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

y este otro para habilitarlo

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Y pude crear una nueva app mediante expo. A pesar de ello aun me salen muchas advertencias a las cuales no se si hacerles mucho caso, las expongo aquí.

> npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or
>   `merge-options` instead.
>
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained
>   and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please,
>   upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained
>   and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please,
>   upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to
>   upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more
>   fetching  binaries from AWS, smaller package size
>
> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit
>   this file. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> added 769 packages from 467 contributors and audited 70680 packages in
>   211.207s found 4 low severity vulnerabilities
>
> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details